# Alternative for r2excel package in R 3.3.3

Tags: r, excel

Until recently I was happily using the `r2excel` package to save multiple data sheets into excel format using the script:

```
library("r2excel")

filename <- "r2excel-example1.xlsx"

wb <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")

sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "example1")

xlsx.addTable(wb, sheet, head(iris), startCol=2)

saveWorkbook(wb, filename)
```

Now that I have updated R to version 3.3.3 this package is no longer available:

```
devtools::install_github("kassambara/r2excel")

Error in loadNamespace(name) : there is no package called ‘curl’*
```

I have found it VERY difficult to export files to excel using any other packages in the old version. Can anyone recommend a solution for exporting multiple dataframes into a single excel file, that is compatible with R3.3.3? 
(saving to CSV is not an option for several reasons including the need for saving multiple sheets in one file).

Thanks

Comment: Did you try to install `RCurl`?

Comment: There is a `xslx` package that allows to work with sheets. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/xlsx/xlsx.pdf

Comment: what operating system? have you tried installing `curl` directly (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/curl/index.html) then re-trying?

Comment: I have good results with `WriteXLS` package, this one allows to work with sheets as well.

Comment: Thank you! I followed Ben Bolkers instruction to install curl directly and now i can install r2excel too. Thanks everyone. I've had problems with both WrtieXLS and xslx so I am very glad to be able to keep r2excel.